# Jquery search for next div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written this code. Its not working but with this you should get idea what i am trying to achieve

```
 $('.jfmfs-alpha-separator').filter(function() {
     return ($(this).next().not(".hide-filtered").hasClass("jfmfs-alpha-separator"));
  }).addClass('hide-filtered');
```

I have number of divs at same level. Below div with class jfmfs-alpha-separator i have number of divs and then div jfmfs-alpha-separator and again number of divs (note with below i mean at same level not child). now when all divs that follow jfmfs-alpha-separator gets class .hide-filtered I  want to hide  that jfmfs-alpha-separator div too.

In my code i am trying to find next div after div with class jfmfs-alpha-separator which does not have 'hide-filtered' class and has jfmfs-alpha-separator class. if this check retutns true i hide that div.

Example:

```
<div class ="jfmfs-alpha-separator">Letter A</div>
<div class ="friend hide-filtered">Aaron</div>
<div class ="friend hide-filtered">Aaron</div>
<div class ="friend hide-filtered">Ashutosh</div>
<div class ="jfmfs-alpha-separator">Letter B</div>
<div class ="friend hide-filtered">Bob</div>
<div class ="friend">Baron</div>
<div class ="friend hide-filtered">Batista</div>
<div class ="jfmfs-alpha-separator">Letter C</div> 
<div class ="friend hide-filtered">Carl</div>
<div class ="friend hide-filtered">Chris</div>
<div class ="friend hide-filtered">Charlie</div>
<div class ="jfmfs-alpha-separator">Letter D</div>
...
```

In above example letter A and C should get hidden because all names below it has got hide-filtered class and Letter B should remain as it is.

How do I achieve this?

Final Solution is used using Salmans Answer :

```
                     $(".jfmfs-alpha-separator").each(function () {
                        if ($(this).nextUntil(".jfmfs-alpha-separator").not('.hide-filtered').length == 0) {
                            $(this).addClass('hide-filtered');
                        }else{
                            $(this).removeClass('hide-filtered');
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to write your code:

```
$(".jfmfs-alpha-separator").each(function () {
    // Assume that all elements after a .jfmfs-alpha-separator but
    // before the next .jfmfs-alpha-separator belong to same group
    var siblings = $(this).nextUntil(".jfmfs-alpha-separator");
    // Now that we have all elements that belong to the group
    // use .filter to see if all elements have .hide-filtered class
    if (siblings.filter(":not(.hide-filtered)").length == 0) {
        console.log("should hide -> ", this);
    }
});
```

It is easy to convert this logic to `.filter(function() {})`

Comment: Thanks I made slight modification and used it. I was not able to do it in 1 single line I too used each function to loop through.

Answer (score 0):

Even though Salman A already gave you a working solution, if possible, you might want to consider some alternatives.

One alternative, with only minor differences, would be to group the divs for every letter, something like this:

```
<div class="group">
  <div class="jfmfs-alpha-separator">Letter A</div>
  <div class="friend hide-filtered">Aaron</div>
  <div class="friend hide-filtered">Aaron</div>
  <div class="friend hide-filtered">Ashutosh</div>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <div class="jfmfs-alpha-separator">Letter B</div>
  <div class="friend hide-filtered">Bob</div>
  <div class="friend">Baron</div>
  <div class="friend hide-filtered">Batista</div>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <div class="jfmfs-alpha-separator">Letter C</div> 
  <div class="friend hide-filtered">Carl</div>
  <div class="friend hide-filtered">Chris</div>
  <div class="friend hide-filtered">Charlie</div>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <div class="jfmfs-alpha-separator">Letter D</div>
</div>
```

You can then update your solution based on Salman's answer to this:

```
$(".group").each(function () {
  if ($(this).children(".friend").not(".hide-filtered").length == 0) {
    $(this).addClass('hide-filtered');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('hide-filtered');
  }
});
```

It doesn't make a whole lot of difference, but I believe it makes both the HTML and the javascript a fair bit easier to read.

Personally, I would also prefer to replace some of the divs with other elements, something like this:

```
<div class="group">
  <h1 class="jfmfs-alpha-separator">Letter A</h1>
  <p class="friend hide-filtered">Aaron</p>
  <p class="friend hide-filtered">Aaron</p>
  <p class="friend hide-filtered">Ashutosh</p>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <h1 class="jfmfs-alpha-separator">Letter B</h1>
  <p class="friend hide-filtered">Bob</p>
  <p class="friend">Baron</p>
  <p class="friend hide-filtered">Batista</p>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <h1 class="jfmfs-alpha-separator">Letter C</h1> 
  <p class="friend hide-filtered">Carl</p>
  <p class="friend hide-filtered">Chris</p>
  <p class="friend hide-filtered">Charlie</p>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <h1 class="jfmfs-alpha-separator">Letter D</h1>
</div>
```

Another alternative, that would require substantially larger changes, would be to implement some sort of data-model. If the above example is the only place on your website where you do this, it might not be worth it, but if you do stuff like this all over the place, it's going to be a huge time-saver.

The basic idea is that you store the data for this list of friends in something like an array, or nested array (which you probably already do, server-side or client-side). You would then apply the logic for showing and hiding elements by counting items in the array, instead of counting DOM-nodes.

KnockoutJS is a great framework for doing stuff like this. I currently use it on a large scale web-app. Be warned though, it's pretty obstrusive, and I would probably not use it on a site that needs to work without javascript.

I'm sure there are other, smaller and simpler, js-libraries that could also help.